# Placeholder settings wildcard keys

Tags: placeholders

I've seen this in some examples, but it didn't seem to work when I tried it out. Basically, take a scenario where you have a placeholder name prefix, like "column" or "row", but in the actual placeholder names you have "column1" and "column2", etc. In the placeholder settings, you want a common placeholder setting for both, so you use the key "column*" to catch both placeholders.

Like I said, I've seen this in a book or article, but not a working code sample, so I don't know if it requires code/pipeline intervention.

Comment: This was either customisation that you saw, or it's how the dynamic placeholders modules such as Fortis have done things by [tapping into the `GetPlaceholderRenerings` pipeline](https://github.com/Fortis-Collection/dynamic-placeholders/blob/master/Source/DynamicPlaceholders/Pipelines/GetPlaceholderRenderings/GetDynamicKeyAllowedRenderings.cs#L20)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new dynamic placeholders of Sitecore 9, you can add a seed.
In this way you can reuse the name of your placeholder and reuse the placeholder settings. However, the placeholders have another key due to their seeds.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/dynamic_placeholders

Example:
@Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("column", seed: 10)